# PHP write file from input to txt - issue

Tags: php, html, forms

I've been at this for a while and been through other options on stack but can't get this to work. (I'm pretty nooby, sorry!)

I have a form which i want to send data to my txt file but it's just not writing.

ANY help greatly appreciated, thank you!!

My HTML Form:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>php test</title>
</head>

    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
        <form action="myprocessingscript.php" method="POST">
    <input name="field1" type="text" />
    <input name="field2" type="text" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Data">
</form>
    <a href='/tmp/mydata.txt'>Text file</a>
</body>
```

And my PHP

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['field1']) && isset($_POST['field2'])) {
    $data = $_POST['field1'] . '-' . $_POST['field2'] . "\n";
    $ret =  fwrite('/tmp/mydata.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    if($ret === false) {
        die('There was an error writing this file');
    }
    else {
        echo "$ret bytes written to file";
    }
}
else {
   die('no post data to process');
}
```

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 1):

You need to open a file before you can write to it with `fwrite()`.

```
$fp = fopen('/tmp/mydata.txt', 'w');
$ret = fwrite($fp, $data);
//and don't forget to close it
fclose($fp);
if($ret === false) { 
   ...
```

Based on the flags you use in the question I think the function you might be thinking of is `file_put_contents` (See Docs [HERE](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)) and not `fwrite`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this line of code:

```
$myfile = fopen("/tmp/mydata.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
```

before the fwrite(), then you can now insert data/text in your file:

```
fwrite($myfile, $data);
```